# Grails 3.1.8 Oracle JDBC Driver configuration

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc, oracle11g

I am trying to connect the Oracle Express Edition 11g through Grails 3.1.8. I tried all possible solutions:

1. Downloaded the jar file(ojdbc14.jar)
2. Adding a pom.xml to my sample application.
3. Searched the entire web for solution.

I was not able to achieve the connectivity between Grails3.1.8 and Oracle.

The only error I see is:

> https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/com/oracle/ojdbc14/10.2.0.4.0/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace (execute gradle with `--stacktrace` as indicated in the error). Also: `ojdbc4.jar` is for Java 1.4 (ie the java version from 2002), you might want to consider a newer driver. If I had to guess, the problem is that the Oracle JDBC driver is not in that repository because of license restriction. You will need to install it in a local repository.

Comment: Hi, I was able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Always use the latest JDBC driver in your application.  JDBC driver is backward compatible with lower versions of the database. You can download the latest drivers from this [path](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html).